# public activity and Notifications in rails

Tags: android-activity, ruby-on-rails-4, notifications, comments

i am designing this little application which consists of Users, Activities,Comments and Notifications.

Users has many activities, Comments and notifications. the Activity was designed following ryan bates tutorial of PublicActivity from scratch [407-activity-feed-from-scratch](http://railscasts.com/episodes/407-activity-feed-from-scratch). and also each Activity has many Comments. for the Notifications, it also belongs to the user in such a way that when a Comment is created, a notification is generated, so far my code includes

User Model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :comments, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :notifications, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :activities, :dependent => :destroy

end  

Activity Model

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :trackable, polymorphic: true

  has_many :comments
  has_many :notifications
  default_scope :order => "activities.created_at DESC"
  #scope :recent, where(published_at: Time.now - 2.weeks)
end
```

Comment Model

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :activity
  belongs_to :user

  default_scope :order => "comments.created_at DESC"
end
```

Notification Model

```
class Notification < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :activity
end
```

in  the controller,

Comments controller i have tried this

```
def new
    @comment = Comment.new
  end

  def create
    @activity = Activity.find(params[:activity_id])

    @comment = @activity.comments.create!(comment_params)
    @comment.user = @user
   @comment.save

    @users= User.joins(:comments).where(comments: {id:           @activity.comment_ids}).push(@activity.user).uniq_by {|a| a[:user_id]}
    @users.each do |user|
      Notification.create(activity_id:@activity, user_id: user.id)
    end

    redirect_to user_path(current_user)

  end
```

Activity Controller

```
def index
    @activities = Activity.all(:include => :comments, :order => "created_at DESC")

    @comments = Comment.find(:all, :order => "created_at DESC")
    @comment = Comment.new
    @comment.user = current_user
 end
```

Notification Controller

```
def index
    @notifications = current_user.notifications

 end
```

WHAT I WANT TO ACHIEVE IS, NOTIFICATIONS SHOULD BE Created And Available To:

1. the owner of the activity cos each activity belongs to a particular user i.e when a new comment is created by another user, a notification is available to the owner of the activity.
2. SHOULD NOT! be available to the new commenter i.e the user that as just commented on the activity but available to owner of the activity
3. Available to all previous commenters i.e every user that as commented on that activity
   and the owner of the activity

. for now my code above does not work  and also is there anything am doing wrong with the model and controllers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

basically what i will do is get all Users that commented on the activity with the following

```
##Activity model

has_many :comments
has_many :users, -> {uniq}, through: :comments
```

So now your new comment create action will look like this

```
def create
    @activity = Activity.find(params[:activity_id])

    @comment = @activity.comments.create!(comment_params)
    @comment.user = @user
    @comment.save

    @users= @activity.users.where("id NOT IN (?)", [@activity.user.id, @comment.user])
   ## Lets create a notification for all those who created a comment in this activity
    @users.each do |user|
      Notification.create(activity:@activity, user: user)                      
    end
    ## Lets create a notification for the owner activity
    Notification.create(activity:@activity, user: @activity.user)  

    redirect_to user_path(current_user)

  end
```

This code is not optimized but can help you out

Comment: the relationship above is rails 4 pattern, dont no if it will work for lower versions of rails.

Comment: hmmm kinda gave me a way to the answer i am grateful.. another question sir uchenna okafor, how can i put the name of the owner of the notification i.e uchenna commented on @activity.id or so...